# Is there a way that we can create Azure DevOps work items using Rest API from Azure Logic apps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have been researching on how i can create/update a work item in Azure DevOps from logic apps using Azure DevOps rest apis? We need this for an integration with another CRM tool. Please reply if this can be done and how?

Thanks,
Gopal

Comment: Provide the information about what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried using the service prinple route. I have created an app registration in azure portal and granted azure devops api permissions. In the logic apps i have been able to get the access token from the app registration. But using the token and calling azure devops api throwing "object moved <some url> here"

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this REST API in order to create work item. You will have to maintain PAT:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Update work item:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

**Or - what I would recommend - you can use Azure DevOps connector (for Logic App it is part of Standard Class):**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/

Create Work item task anchor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#create-a-work-item

Update work item task anchor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#update-a-work-item

Simple guide how to set up such task in Logic App:
https://codegumbo.com/index.php/2021/05/27/using-an-azure-logic-app-to-create-azuredevops-work-items-from-a-sql-server-dataset/

Comment: Thanks Danielson. Using the Create work item task would require a service account. We would like to bypass the service account and use service prinicple process work item creation or updation. I tried follwing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops . But this seems to be a longer process and doesn't have a feeling that it works with out hurdles

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I have received the same error.

> [image]

You are receiving this because as soon as you try to hit the endpoint it asks for login which requires token and hence you are getting redirected. One of the workarounds to make this work is to provide required scope as mentioned in this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=/azure/devops/organizations/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/organizations/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=azure-devops).

One of the ways that worked for me is to use the DevOps Connector directly from logic apps. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]